# How to annotate @attributes in google-closure interfaces

Tags: javascript, json, google-closure-compiler, jsdoc

How can I annotate the interface of a JSON-response in google closure?

I have to use a JSONP interface which actually transforms some XML into JSON and provides it as a parameter to my callback. But unfortunately the origin XML contains some attributes so I get a JSON-Object with @attributes-fields e.g.

```
{
  "output": {
    "foo": "bar"
  },
  "@attributes": {
    "baz": "attr"
  }
}
```

I created an google-closure interface so the compiler will not minify my fields by accident and I get the neat auto-complition in my IDE.

```
/**
 * @interface
 */
var JsonResult = function() {};

/**
 * @type {JsonResultOutput}
 */
JsonResult.prototype.output;

/**
 * @type {JsonResultAttributes}
 */
JsonResult.prototype['@attributes'];

/**
 * @interface
 */
var JsonResultOutput = function() {};

/**
 * @type {string}
 */
JsonResultOutput.prototype.foo;

/**
 * @interface
 */
var JsonResultAttributes = function() {};

/**
 * @type {string}
 */
JsonResultAttributes.prototype.baz;
```

Unfortunetly the compiler fires a warning if I try to annotate fields in brackets and strings. So my question is now: How should I annotate this to remove the warning? Maybe I can just remove this field in the interface, due to the problem that I have to write this field in the same way in the code as well, so the compiler will never minify this field. But I also want to document the object in it's full structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like a bug to me. Feel free to file an issue at https://github.com/google/closure-compiler

For a workaround, you'll have to use object literal keys:

```
JsonResult.prototype = {
  /**
   * @type {JsonResultAttributes}
   */
  '@attributes': {} 
};
```

Comment: Thanks for the great idea. I made a workaround by transforming the result right after loading into a more target-oriented format and annotated only the other fields. I also added a descriptive comment to the transformation and to the interface to document the problem, but your solution look much better. Nevertheless I'll write a ticket for that behavior to clarify how this can be handled correctly.